# Are there a mode like hibernate but still run server in Windows? (or any OS)

Tags: windows, docker, webserver, hibernate

This is my first post so apologize in advance if I did anything wrong for this exchange site

I am using windows and use hibernate on daily basis. The main goal to use hibernate is actually to mitigate the power outage or brownout outside of work hour. My PC has slow startup time and so I don't want to shutdown or start it in fresh state

However, now I want to open a simple server just to serve some website and files (or even some service) in my own PC

Which made me want have a command to let windows go into a state that very similar to hibernate, but still running the web server in the background with bare minimum power usage. And the most important part is save a state of windows itself into `hiberfil` and ready to use again anytime like normal hibernate

If possible I would like to have my computer always kept running in this state, restart itself when brownout or after blackout. But not run actual desktop until I wake it up

Is there any solution similar to this?

ps. If possible I would like to run docker and leave it run in the background

Comment: You need a UPS.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a small server to run while your main server is off, I would suggest something like a Raspberry Pi and run it off that

What you are trying to do sounds pretty much impossible to me

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot hibernate a computer without actually hibernating it.

Hibernation stores the entire state of the system to disk. Included in that hibernation is the state of devices, the disk and a lot of other stuff.

If you leave the computer running for any time after writing the final bytes to disk then changes will happen to the disk and system that do not match up with the state saved in the hibernation file.

The result is that the hibernation file is immediately invalid but assumed to be correct. As a result it may restore the system and use an old version of filesystem tables that are no longer correct and so (in the best case) simply drop changes that may have happened to the disk since it was hibernated and at worst result in corruption.

If your system disk is slow then you might want to look into replacing an HDD with an SDD which can improve boot times.

You may also want to look into small dedicated machines to act as servers.